# Javascript / webjars/ace using wrong url

Tags: javascript, laravel, requirejs, xtext, webjars

Hello everyone so a quick explanation.

I am running a laravel project and I'm integrating (trying to) with x-text.

My problem now is this

[image]

As shown in the image I want the createEditor to use localhost:8080, because it is the language server, so it will always be this even if I release this. The first time it worked, on the require.config and I have no ideia on what is this different.

My problem is that it uses both, the url I give and the Url of the page I'm on.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thank you all!

Things I've tried:
baseUrl, url, http, href, using the url started by //

Comment: language server and webjars dont have todo anything with each other. can you elaborate what exactly you are doing?

Comment: i assume you are using pure xtext-web, no language server?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich So I want to be able to use my x-text dsl in laravel with auto-complete, errors lined just like I have when I make a eclipse project, check web integration and run it with gradlew jettyRun.
I'm doing all that but I get that error, what I'm doing is I placed all the x-text projects files inside public and runned it from there

Comment: you might try something like `var myBaseUrl = window.location.pathname;` and use that one in the config. alternatively: can you provide sample code i can check out?

Comment: https://github.com/joaofrf/TestesProjetoInformatico
Here is my testing project

Comment: The path doesn't change I've tried using that varible (which comes with the default web integration from eclipse)

Comment: from your sample code i dont see how to use it and so reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I run the project like a normal laravel app, and go to the public folder and run gradlew jettyRun. If you have skype/discord/microsoft teams, if you're willing to help me ofcourse, i have all of those

Comment: sorry i have no idea about laravel

Comment: Laravel is basicly php but using the oop principles

Thank you anyways for your time